# What does the compiler do when it converts a float variable to an integer variable?

Tags: c++, types, casting, floating-point, int

What does the compiler do? The aim is to get the number after the point as an integer. I did it like this:

```
float a = 0;
cin >> a;

int b = (a - (int)a)*10;
```

Now my problem is this: when I enter for example 3.2, I get 2, which is what I want. It also works with .4, .5 and .7. but when I enter for example 2.3, I get 2. For 2.7 I get 6 and so on. But when I do it without variables, for example:

```
(2.3 - (int)2.3)*10;
```

I get the correct result.

I couldn't figure out what the compiler does. I alway thought when I cast a float to an integer, then it simply cuts at the point. This is what the compiler actually does when I use constant numbers. However, when I use variables, the compiler reduces some of them, but not all.

Comment: You're getting bit by the fact that float numbers are inexact, and printing them will round the least digit, while (int) does no rounding.

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely not having problems with the compiler, but with the fact that floating point numbers cannot be represented exactly on a binary computer.

So, when you do:

```
float f = 2.7f;
```

..what might actually be stored in the computer is:

```
2.6999999999999999
```

This is a very well-known characteristic of floating points on binary computers.  There are many posts on SO that discuss this.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the problem comes from the fact that binary has different "infinitely repeating" values than base 10 does.  For instance.  1/10 in decimal is 0.1,  in binary, it's 0.000110011001100110011001100...  The problem is caused because floating point cannot hold 2.3 correctly because it's an infinite number of binary digits, but it approximates closely, probably as 2.2999999.  For most math, it's the close enough.  But be wary of truncation.

One solution is to round before you truncate.

```
int b = (a - (int)(a+.05))*10;
```

Also note that floating point values have different sizes in memory than in the registers, which means you have to round when comparing if two floating point values are *equal* as well.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the discrepancy is that by default, floating point literals are doubles, which have higher accuracy, and are more closely able to represent the value you're looking for.

Comment: They seems both to be <= 2.3 And even the 80 bit version seems to be the same :-) http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=2.3

Comment: @xanatos You're right.  I guess it's based on how the floating point value is rounded.  I'll remove the second paragraph from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like this?

```
b = (a*10)%10;
```

I find it a lot easier.